# How to hash and download images with request?

Tags: node.js, http, async-await, buffer, node-request

## Situation

What I want to achieve, is download an image to a buffer, hash it, **then** save it.

I can not write to disk **before** hashing.

## Code (inside a Promise)

```
const filename = this.getPathFromHash(hash);
if (!fs.existsSync(path.dirname(filename))) fs.mkdirSync(path.dirname(filename));
fs.writeFile(filename, body, 'binary', (e) => {
  if (e) reject(e);
  parser.MediumVersion.create({
    hash, url, type, size, width, height,
  }).then(resolve).catch(reject);
});
```

## Result

file corruption, but it created the files :)

Edit: IrFanView says that it's JPEG with an incorrect extension, then it just says **not** a jpeg file, starts with (two random bytes here)

Edit2: What is this?? Four 0xfd bytes? What do they mean? Otherwise the image header looks OK.

[image: fdfdfdfd]

Edit3: Removing those bytes do not solve the problem :/ Maybe encoding is the culprit? I've tried changing it to `UTF-8`, no luck so far.

Edit4: Quick comparison! 1st one downloaded using my program, second one, Chrome.

[image: comparison]

## Directory structure

I know, I know, SHA-256 hashes are 64 characters long. For the sake of simplicity, I'm going to use 8 characters.

Given the hash `0123abcd`, create the directory `01` (if it doesn't exist (`slice(0,2)`), then put the file with name `23abcd` (`slice(2)`) in it. I've seen this structure in lots of caches.

### Example:

```
01/
  23abcd
  45abcd
ab/
  cdef01
  010101
```

Answer (score 0):

As per https://github.com/request/request#requestoptions-callback:

> if you expect binary data, you should set `encoding: null`.

So for me that would be `request(url, { encoding: null }, (e, resp, body) => {...})`.

In that case, the image is perfectly fine and readable :)